# How to merge 2 bitmap with config ALPHA_8 in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

If I load a bitmap with ALPHA_8 it will create an bitmap with the a greyscale and transparancy. This is exactly what I want.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_bitmap, options);
```

I want to merge two bitmaps. To do so I create a canvas with ALPHA_8 and draw the same bitmap on the canvas.

But the result is different. It will keep the alpha, but everything what was grey will be black. So I see only the contours and no greyscale.

```
resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
resultCanvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
resultCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

I found 2 workarounds.

A) Use ARGB_8888 instead of ALPHA_8, but this will result in a far larger image.

```
resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

B) Use a color matrix to convert the image to alpha channel, but this will result in the grey to be semi transparant, instead of a grey scale.

```
float[] matrix = new float[] {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            -1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0};
Paint grayToAlpha = new Paint();
grayToAlpha.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(matrix)));
resultCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, grayToAlpha);
```

Both workarounds are not perfect. So my question is:

Is there a way to get the same result with the canvas as with the bitmap?

Or

Is there a better way of merging two bitmaps with ALPHA_8 together?

Comment: exactly what is meant by "merging"? Average? Sum?

Comment: Adding them together. So, I meant Sum.